# Drupal 8 Generate all images for all styles

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-modules

I'm working on a Drupal 8.6 multi site installation, where every site has it's own database, and I'm having a problem where the first time a content is shared on Facebook it uses the wrong image.

The meta tag is configured right, it is something like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://xxxx.com/image.jpg?itok=w8tMeCC0" />
```

This image problem happens **only at the first share** and I believe it happens because the image has not been created yet at the moment of the first share.

I would like to know what I could do to force the image to be generated as soon as the content is published and if there is a way to create all the missing images.

I found [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/252415/apply-image-styles-for-migrated-images) and I'm trying to implement in a module (I never worked on Drupal before) but I don't even know how to schedule this piece of script to be executed.

Is there an existing module or setting that does that?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the facebook Debugger?
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
Facebook usually stores the metatags in cache during shares. What I usually do is debug the webpage at least once with the right metatags configured in the debugger and ensure the page loads correctly there. 
Afterwards, the share will be loading all the assets correctly.